# Shell variables as autoconf macro input

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I need to check for Erlang libraries on my configure.ac but the list of erlang apps is on a separate file, and I have to run a program to extract that list.

Normally, I can do this:

```
AC_ERLANG_CHECK_LIB([app1])
AC_ERLANG_CHECK_LIB([app2])
```

However, since the actual apps are on a separate file (and I don't want to repeat them on configure.ac, I was thinking on doing somewhere along the lines of:

```
DEPS=`some command that gets app1, app2`
# DEPS=app1 app2

m4_foreach_w(dep, "$DEPS", [AC_ERLANG_CHECK_LIB([dep])])
```

I know that "$DEPS" is the wrong argument here, since it needs the actual value for that - something like [app1 app2]. I also know that the evaluation of the DEPS variable isn't done untile ./configure is called, while m4_foreach_w requires the value of DEPS prior.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
m4_foreach_w(dep, m4_esyscmd([some command that generates list]),
       [AC_ERLANG_CHECK_LIB(dep)])
```

I suspect that this is a bad idea, but am unable to give more details on potential pitfalls.  If it were me, I would prefer to hard code the dependencies or generate the `configure.ac` with a script.

Comment: Hm. Care to expound why it's a bad idea?

Comment: @jvliwanag  My only concern is the m4 quoting; it tends to be easy to generate hard to track bugs.  On the other hand, a script to generate configure.ac is probably even more fragile.  I'm simply wary of `m4_esyscmd`.  Perhaps overly so.

Answer (score 0):

This approach might be total overkill for you but I'll just describe it.

When you run your program to get the list, munge the output into [GNU Autogen](http://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/) .def file format:

**elib.def**

```
autogen definitions elib;

elib = { name="app1"; };
elib = { name="app2"; };
```

then invoke `autogen` with a template file like this:

**gen.tpl**

```
[+ autogen5 template 
m4=%s.m4
(setenv "SHELL" "/bin/sh") +]#
[+ (dne "# " "# ") +]
# whatever comment for the macro
AC_DEFUN([CHECK_MY_ELIBS],
[
[+
FOR elib "\n" +]AC_ERLANG_CHECK_LIB([[+name+]])[+ENDFOR+]
])
```

which'll output a macro **elib.m4**:

```
...
# whatever comment for the macro
AC_DEFUN([CHECK_MY_ELIBS],
[
AC_ERLANG_CHECK_LIB([app1])
AC_ERLANG_CHECK_LIB([app2])
])
```

You then invoke CHECK_MY_ELIBS in `configure.ac` after installing elib.m4 in `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR`.

You could of course generate elib.m4 by some other means (e.g. perl, python), but this is not too hard.